# Where should the submit button be for these type of compact forms? (bootstrap 3 module)

Tags: forms, layout, submit, fluid-layout

So, I'm creating a compact **form** module for bootstrap 3. The project is [opensource on github](https://github.com/alexanis/Compact-form). This type of **forms** are good in two ways: It's so 2014 and very user friendly on mobile devices.

But Im having a problem on where to put to submit button? Where is the best place?

PS! Auto submitting is not an option. The form has a fluid layout.

Open the image in a new tab for larger version.

[image]

Answer:
The options seems to outside of the borders, bottom-left. But honestly it doesnt feel good to me. If you have a better approach please suggest.
[image]

My own suggestion:
[image]

Comment: To give it a little context are you able to change it to English :) Also can you give a screenshot of the entire page?

Comment: Tim, image has been updated!

Comment: thanks. I would post an answer but it would be almost identical to @salman now!

Comment: Ps. I like the green positive button in the first screenshot of yours. This is good placement as it is where users will expect it and also having it on its own "line" will reduce errors on mobiles and tablets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Towards the bottom-left end of the form, outside the bounding block. It is because,

- users scan from left-to-right and top-to-bottom. Placing anything on the bottom-left end of the form block will be noticeable immediately.
- An input box placed at the bottom-left doesn't need to be starkly visible and a button using similar form-style will be seen, but if you place anything on the bottom-right corner of the form, it must have a high-contrast background colour.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If it's not a long form, the conventional placement for a submit button is below the form, left aligned.

[image]

Reference: [Primary & Secondary Actions in Web Forms](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?571)